# How can I record 2 microphone in Android simultaneously?

Tags: android, audio-recording, microphone, galaxy

I'm trying to record audio signals from 2 in-built microphone(bottom, top) at the same time. I can pick up bottom microphone signal using

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
```

and top microphone signal using

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER
```

I can record separately but I want to record at the same time from 2 microphones. 
Does anyone know how to record simultaneously?
I tried & or | operator but I can get only 1 channel signal.

I use Galaxy S2 device.

I will appreciate any response :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I certainly would not assume that `MIC` is bottom, `CAMCORDER` is top, and that they are distinct on all devices.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing and encountered the same problem

Answer (score 3):

There is a misconception that in devices with 2 microphones, both the microphones will be used when recording in the stereo mode.

In my 3 years experience of testing on tens of devices, I have found that this was never the case.

The primary mic **alone** is used **both in mono and stereo recording** in the wide range of Android devices that I have worked with - from low-cost mass models to flagships.

One reason for this is that the primary mic is of a better quality (more sensitive, less noisy, etc.) and costlier than the secondary mic.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by doing a stereo recording using the AudioRecord (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class. Have a look at [How to access the second mic android such as Galaxy 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418267/how-to-access-the-second-mic-android-such-as-galaxy-3).

Specifying the audio format as stereo and the audio source as the camcorder automatically selects two microphones, one for each channel, on a (compatible) two microphone device.

For example:

```
            audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,sampleRate,android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize);
```

will initialise a new AudioRecord class, that can record from two device microphones in stereo in PCM, 16 bit format.

For more help on recording using AudioRecord (to record .wav), have a look at: http://i-liger.com/article/android-wav-audio-recording.