# Android - Splitting data from different channels (left and right)

Tags: android, audio, microphone, pcm, audiotrack

**What I need to do:** 
I am supposed to do a stereo recording. 
So when I clicked "Record", the left speaker will generate 400HZ freq and right speaker will generate 500HZ and I have to record it. Then I have to convert to audio format (mp3,wav,flac etc)

I have managed to do the above (except for converting to audio format which is not done yet)

Below is my code

```
package com.exercise.AndroidAudioRecord;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidAudioRecordActivity extends Activity {

    String[] freqText = {"11.025 KHz (Lowest)", "16.000KHZ", "18.000 KHz", "19.000 KHz", "22.050 KHz", "44.100 KHz (Highest)"};
    Integer[] freqset = {11025, 16000, 18000, 19000, 22050, 44100};
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    Spinner spFrequency;
    Button startRec, stopRec, playBack;

    Boolean recording;
    /* Generate the frequency tone */
    int sample;
    double sampleRate;
    double duration;    
    double time;
    double f1;
    double f2;
    double amplitude1;
    double amplitude2;
    double sineWave1;
    double sineWave2;
    float[] buffer1;
    float[] buffer2;
    byte[] byteBuffer1;
    byte[] byteBuffer2;
    byte[] byteBufferFinal;
    int bufferIndex;    
    short x; 
    short y;
    short [] leftChannelAudioData;
    short [] rightChannelAudioData;
    AudioTrack audioTrack;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startrec);
        stopRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stoprec);
        playBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playback);

        startRec.setOnClickListener(startRecOnClickListener);
        stopRec.setOnClickListener(stopRecOnClickListener);
        playBack.setOnClickListener(playBackOnClickListener);

        spFrequency = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.frequency);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, freqText);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spFrequency.setAdapter(adapter);

        stopRec.setEnabled(false);

        sampleRate = 44100.0;
        duration = 20.0;
        f1 = 400.0; 
        //f1 = 18000.0;
        amplitude1= 1;
        f2 = 500;
        //f2 =19000.0;
        amplitude2 = 1;

        buffer1 = new float[(int)(duration*sampleRate)];
        buffer2 = new float[(int)(duration*sampleRate)];

        for(sample = 0; sample < buffer1.length; sample ++){
            time = sample / sampleRate;
            buffer1[sample] = (float)(amplitude1*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*f1*time));
            buffer2[sample] = (float)(amplitude2*Math.sin(2*Math.PI*f2*time));  
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        byteBuffer1 = new byte[buffer1.length*2]; //two bytes per audio frame, 16 bits

        for(int a = 0, bufferIndex=0; a < byteBuffer1.length; a++){
            x = (short) (buffer1[bufferIndex++]*32767.0); // [2^16 - 1]/2 = 32767.0
            byteBuffer1[a] = (byte) x; // low byte
            byteBuffer1[++a] = (byte) (x >>> 8);  // high byte          
        }


        byteBuffer2 = new byte[buffer2.length*2];

        for(int j = 0, bufferIndex=0; j < byteBuffer2.length; j++){
            y = (short) (buffer2[bufferIndex++]*32767.0);
            byteBuffer2[j] = (byte) y;         // low byte
            byteBuffer2[++j] = (byte) (y >>> 8);  // high byte

        }

        byteBufferFinal = new byte[byteBuffer1.length*2]; 
        //LL RR LL RR LL RR 
        for(int k = 0, index = 0; index < byteBufferFinal.length - 4; k=k+2){
            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer1[k]; // LEFT {0,1/4,5/8,9/12,13;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index+1] = byteBuffer1[k+1];
            index = index + 2;
            byteBufferFinal[index] = byteBuffer2[k]; // RIGHT {2,3/6,7/10,11;...}
            byteBufferFinal[index+1] = byteBuffer2[k+1];
            index = index + 2;
        }

        /*
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                (int) sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, byteBufferFinal.length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        audioTrack.write(byteBufferFinal, 0, byteBufferFinal.length);
        audioTrack.play();
        */

        /*End of frequency tone */
    }

    OnClickListener startRecOnClickListener
    = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recording = true;
                    startRecord();
                }

            });

            recordThread.start();
            startRec.setEnabled(false);
            stopRec.setEnabled(true);

        }};

    OnClickListener stopRecOnClickListener
    = new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            recording = false;
            startRec.setEnabled(true);
            stopRec.setEnabled(false);
            Log.d("TEST", "THIS IS INSIDE STOP");      
            audioTrack.flush(); 
            audioTrack.stop(); 
            audioTrack.release();
        }};

    OnClickListener playBackOnClickListener
        = new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playRecord();
            }
    };

    private void startRecord(){

          audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    (int) sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, byteBufferFinal.length,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
            audioTrack.write(byteBufferFinal, 0, byteBufferFinal.length);
            audioTrack.play();

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm"); 

        int selectedPos = spFrequency.getSelectedItemPosition();
        int sampleFreq = freqset[selectedPos];

        final String promptStartRecord = 
                "startRecord()\n"
                + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n"
                + (String)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(AndroidAudioRecordActivity.this, 
                        promptStartRecord, 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleFreq, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, 
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            //AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
                    sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            while(recording){
                int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            audioRecord.release();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    void playRecord(){
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
        //int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length());
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            int selectedPos = spFrequency.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int sampleFreq = freqset[selectedPos];
            //int sampleFreq1 = 400;
            //int sampleFreq2 = 20000;
            final String promptPlayRecord = 
                    "PlayRecord()\n"
                    + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n"
                    + (String)spFrequency.getSelectedItem();

            Toast.makeText(AndroidAudioRecordActivity.this, 
                    promptPlayRecord, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            AudioTrack audioTrack1 = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    sampleFreq,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    //audioData.length,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            //int stereo=audioTrack.setStereoVolume(0.0f, 1.0f);
            audioTrack1.play();
            audioTrack1.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);         
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**Question 1.1:** Is it possible to have the top mic record the 400HZ and the bottom mic to record 500HZ and when I click play, the left and right speaker will play 400HZ and 500HZ respectively?

**Question 1.2:** If the above is not possible, how do I separate the left and right channels? (I saw this link but I am not sure how to implement it [How to access the second mic android such as Galaxy 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418267/how-to-access-the-second-mic-android-such-as-galaxy-3))

**Question 2:** How do I convert PCM file to wav,mp3,flac format etc?

Thanks for all help and advices. Greatly appreciated it!