# Is it possible to record audio from two mic inputs independently at a time

Tags: android

Tried to create new audiorecord instances like

```
 mAudioInstance = new Record(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 mAudioInstanceSecond = new Record(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
```

So when I tried to start recording I got the following warning message for second record instance
"startInput() input failed: other input already started"

So I cant use second mic for recording, only able to record for first mic

Is there anyway to use two audio inputs for recording at a time for an anddoid device

Note : I am using Nexus 9 which have a mic port near camera, so I believe the second mic instance is a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by doing a stereo recording using the AudioRecord

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)

Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15418720/7795876

Specifying the audio format as stereo and the audio source as the camcorder automatically selects two microphones, one for each channel, on a (compatible) two microphone device.

Eg:-

```
    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER,
            sampleRate, android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
            android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
```

this will initialise a new AudioRecord class, that can record from two device microphones in stereo in PCM, 16 bit format.