# How to read data from multiple microphones using Android's Oboe/AAudio

Tags: android, c++, audio-recording, opensl, oboe

I'm interesting in accessing both microphone on a phone using the Android Oboe library. Most phones have a dual-mic configuration and I'd like to read data from both at the same time. I've extended the "LiveAffect" sample from Oboe, and tried the following:

1. Having two oboe::AudioStream, one for each microphone on my phone (Note 9 and Pixel 1). Running only one of the streams works fine, I'm able to read the data and play it back/save to file. But starting both streams doesn't work (I get the following error when attempting to start the second stream via `stream->requestStart()`: **E/AUDIO-APP: Error starting stream. ErrorInvalidState**). Apparently starting two input streams is an Android limitation as discussed in this SO question: [Android Oboe Library: 2 streams recording from 2 recording devices possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796802/android-oboe-library-2-streams-recording-from-2-recording-devices-possible)
2. Having one stream but with 2 channels. The two mics on my Note 9 are part of the same group, yet when I open a stream with either of them with 2 channels (`->setChannelCount(oboe::ChannelCount::Stereo);`), I get duplicate data in both channels for only one microphone. I've tried playing around with `AudioStreamBuilder` settings, for example setting `->setInputPreset(oboe::InputPreset::Camcorder)`. None of the `InputPresets` settings fixed it, still mirrored data in both channels.

Both attempts did not work using OpenSL backend either.

Comment: "The two mics on my Note 9 are part of the same group" - what do you mean by "same group"?

Comment: The number returned from MicrophoneInfo.getGroup()  (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MicrophoneInfo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is a problem with that particular device. A user reported an identical issue on the [JUCE forum here](https://forum.juce.com/t/2-channel-recording-appears-as-1-duplicated-channel-on-only-some-android-devices/31630). I have filed a bug internally (id: 133143785) and will attempt to route this to Samsung for further investigation.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get a stereo input of both microphones (either AAUDIO or SLES ) on a Samsung S8 was to set:

```
builder->setDeviceId(0) // mandatory ! if set to the microphone id you get only one mic!
builder->setDirection(oboe::Direction::Input) // obvious
builder->setChannelCount(2) // obvious
builder->setFormat(oboe::AudioFormat::I16) // with oboe converter float should work to
builder->setInputPreset(oboe::InputPreset::Generic) // or oboe::InputPreset::Camcorder
builder->setUsage(oboe::Usage::Media) // unsure if this is ness.
```

Odd thing I noticed, androids AudioManager.getDevices (AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_ALL) on this device returns a different list after you used the audio in mono ( 2 x TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC ) or stereo ( 1x TYPE_BUILTIN_MIC ) all having AudioDeviceInfo.getChannelCounts() list = [1,2] !

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only configuration that gave me stereo mics as well. As soon as a specific mic ID is specified, I get a duplicated mono signal.