# How to generate 2 different sounds from 2 built-in speakers simultaneously

Tags: android, oboe

Is it possible to play 2 different sounds simultaneously from 2 built-in speakers (1=main speaker, 2=earpiece speaker) on Android, preferably using [Oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) C++ library.

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53796802/android-oboe-library-2-streams-recording-from-2-recording-devices-possible), it was asked a similar question, but for 2 different audio devices. In my case, I just want to play on the same audio device but through 2 different speakers.

It was possible to record data from built-in microphones simultaneously using stereo channels. A similar approach for speakers didn't work.

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Note:

> The term Audio Device refers to a device capable of receiving or
>   sending audio. An audio device can have multiple microphones and/or
>   speakers attached to it, and these are represented as different
>   channels.

Debugging device is Google Pixel XL running Android 9

Answer (score 0):

If the audio device has 2 speakers then you should be able to play different sounds through each speaker by supplying different data to each channel.

However, I believe the speakers you're referring to:

> 2 built-in speakers (1=main speaker, 2=earpiece speaker)

are actually 2 separate audio devices each with a single speaker. In which case you won't be able to use them at the same time, although [hacks might be available](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/enable-true-stereo-sound-your-pixel-xl-0174749/) to make the speakers part of the same audio device (I haven't tried this).