# How to set sound playback from external speaker?

Tags: android, kotlin

There is a kind of weird issue, I am using `oboe` lib https://github.com/google/oboe, for sound playback. Of course you can choose sound playback output according to android settings

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioDeviceInfo

So, if I need to set exact output chanel I need to set it to oboe lib.

By the way output chanal that I need is `TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER`, but on some devices (sometimes, not constantly) I hear the sound from
`TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE`

How I am doing this, I have such method to get needed chanel id

```
fun findAudioDevice(app: Application,
                            deviceFlag: Int,
                            deviceType: Int): AudioDeviceInfo?
        {
            var result: AudioDeviceInfo? = null
            val manager = app.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            val adis = manager.getDevices(deviceFlag)

            for (adi in adis)
            {
                if (adi.type == deviceType)
                {
                    result = adi
                    break
                }
            }

            return result
        }
```

How I use it

```
val id = getAudioDeviceInfoId(getBuildInSpeakerInfo())

private fun getBuildInSpeakerInfo(): AudioDeviceInfo?
    {
        return com.tetavi.ar.basedomain.utils.Utils.findAudioDevice( //
                getApplication<Application>(), //
                AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, //
                AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER //
        )
    }

private fun getAudioDeviceInfoId(info: AudioDeviceInfo?): Int
    {
        var result = -1

        if (info != null)
        {
            result = info.id
        }

        return result
    }
```

And eventually I need to set this `id` to `oboe` lib. `Oboe` lib is native lib, so with JNI I pass this id and set it

```
oboe::Result oboe_engine::createPlaybackStream()
{
    oboe::AudioStreamBuilder builder;
    const oboe::SharingMode sharingMode = oboe::SharingMode::Exclusive;
    const int32_t sampleRate = mBackingTrack->getSampleRate();
    const oboe::AudioFormat audioFormat = oboe::AudioFormat::Float;
    const oboe::PerformanceMode performanceMode = oboe::PerformanceMode::PowerSaving;

    builder.setSharingMode(sharingMode)
            ->setPerformanceMode(performanceMode)
            ->setFormat(audioFormat)
            ->setCallback(this)
            ->setSampleRate(sampleRate);

    if (m_output_playback_chanel_id != EMPTY_NUM)
    {
        //set output playback chanel (like internal or external speaker)
        builder.setDeviceId(m_output_playback_chanel_id);                  <------------- THIS LINE
    }

    return builder.openStream(&mAudioStream);
}
```

So, actually issue is that on some devices (sometimes, not constantly) I still hear that sound playback goes from internal speaker `TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE` inspite of I set directly that I need to use `TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER`

I checked a few times the flow, from moment that I get this `id` (it is acctually is 3) and up to the moment when I set it as a param to `oboe` lib, but still sometimes I hear sound from internal speaker.

So, question is - if I miss something here? Maybe some trick should be implemented or something else?