# Is there a way to open two parallel capture(recording) sessions in Android?

Tags: android, audio-recording

1. How to open two parallel recording sessions in Andorid ?
2. If (1) is possible , How to know the session count i.e number of active recording session opened ?

I searched the portal but didnt find anything relevent on this topic ?

Comment: You can take benefit of multithreading.

Comment: I hope this link might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627246/how-can-i-record-2-microphone-in-android-simultaneously