# How to use both the top and the bottom mics of Samsung Galaxy s4?

Tags: android

I am developing and testing an app which does playing a pcm file and recording the sound to a new pcm file at the same time on galaxy s4. I want to use both mics of this phone, but I have found that the data I got in my way are the same. This means the data I get are just replication of the same mic.

I used the AudioRecord class and AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO to record sound. I used the method described by Michael in this link [How to access the second mic android such as Galaxy 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418267/how-to-access-the-second-mic-android-such-as-galaxy-3) to try to get both mic's data. However, it seems that it does not work because they are the same data.

I am wondering how can I use the other mic of this galaxy s4?

Any thoughts or comments are welcomed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution.

I solved it by referencing the answer to this question, Visit [How can I record 2 microphone in Android simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627246/how-can-i-record-2-microphone-in-android-simultaneously)